# Something easy got wrong

Tags: python

English is not my strong language, please considerate it.

What I'm trying to do is make a 3x3, 4x4 or 5x5 matrix of "~" signs, that would get replaced by "X" 3 times,

Depending on coordinates given by x and y inputs, appended in s=[]

So for example if I have a matrix 3x3

```
~~~
~~~
~~~
```

And coordinate (0,0),

The result should be:

```
X~~
~~~
~~~
```

As easy as it sounds it's not easy for me still, I get problem even if my code seems logical to me.

```
> IndexError: list index out of range
```

This is my code:

```
a = []

n=0
while n<3 or n>5:
    n=int(raw_input("type matrix: "))
for i in range (n):
    for j in range (n):
        print "~",
    print "\n",
def zdruzi(a):
    for row in a:
        print " ".join(row)
zdruzi(a)

s = []
for i in range(3):
    x=int(raw_input("x: "))
    y=int(raw_input("y: "))
    s.append(int(x))
    s.append(int(y))
    a[int(x)][int(y)]="X"

    if (x<0) or (x>(n-1)):
        print "not good"
        break

    print a
```

Comment: Since `x` and `y` are the product of calling `int(…)`, you don't need to call `int(x)` or `int(y)`. Just use `x` and `y` directly.

Comment: Yes I see, i made a few redundant int(...) callings. But I tested it many times with just using x and y directly, and I still get the same error.

Comment: The redundant calls aren't the cause of your problem. I was merely pointing them out as a comment.

Comment: Also, you should test that `x` is in range before using it, not after.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You haven't prepopulated `a`. After reading `n`, do this:

```
a = [ [ '~' for _ in range(n) ] for _ in range(n) ]
```

Comment: Yes (except i18n blahblahblah), but since strings are immutable you don't need the special casing for the inner loop.

Comment: @IgnacioVazquez-Abrams: Are you saying I should have written `['~'] * n`? I suppose I could have, but the above feels more regular.

Comment: I'm not saying that you *should* have, I'm just noting that you *could* have.

Comment: Hi. This helps A LOT. but we're not quite there yet.

ATM it only shows "x" in A, for the last series of x and y. How do I do it so that it will show 3 x's in my a=[]?

Comment: @academeniaan: You'll have to be more specific.

Comment: yes. I've inserted your code right before my: a[int(x)][int(y)]="X"

and the result is, that only one (out of 3) "X"'s shows on my board. Suggestions?

Comment: @academeniaan: Read my answer more carefully.

Comment: OH this is good. You're awesome. It's 1 AM, i'm really really tired and I wasn't concentrated enough, but now it works GREAT

THANKS A LOT CANTOS!!